# Why did the kids kill Katie?

Tags: mystic-river

Why did the kids kill Katie in *Mystic River*? Was it because she was taking Brendan away from Silent Ray?

Answer (score 4):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystic_River_(film)#Plot):

> Silent Ray and John O'Shea stole Just Ray's pistol and attempted to menace a random car, but they accidentally shot and wounded Katie. **To cover up their crime**, they chased her into the park, where Silent Ray beat her with a hockey stick and John O'Shea shot her a second time, killing her.